# Check If my String is Prime

Tags: code-golf, string

We define a *prime character* as a character that has a [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) [ASCII value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). We define a *prime string* as a String that only contains *prime* characters.

Given a String that only contains printable ASCII, determine whether that String is prime.

### Input / Output

You can take input either as a String or as a list of individual characters. You have to output two different and ***consistent*** values depending on whether the String is prime, following the standard rules for a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem). You are guaranteed that the input will be non-empty.

### Test Cases

**Truthy cases (Prime Strings):**

```
"aeg"
"aIS5"
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
"/S/S"
"=;+"
```

**Falsy cases (not Prime Strings):**

```
"maTHS"
"Physics"
"\\\\"
"PPCG"
"Code Golf"
"Prime"
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins! Standard rules for this tag apply.

Comment: It's not very unique, though I +1'd it.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I downvoted (and I personally would say dupe) of generic prime checking with some boilerplate (`.unicodePoints.every(isPrime)`) the thing is none of these boilerplate functions would even likely have the capability to be golfed as they are isPrime surrounded by language built ins. I don't want to smash as I would hammer it and would also like to get consensus

Comment: The definition of a prime string as simply not containing any non-prime characters seems less interesting than it could be, and a poor analogy with digits of numbers.  For example, in regular decimal numbers, 33 is non-prime even though all its digits are prime.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
OÆPẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFvAw10L/h9uf9S05v//aKXE1HQlHaVEz2BTEIUCgAL6wfrBQMrWWhtI5iaGeIB4ARmVxZnJxUBWDBCABAKc3YGUc35KqoJ7fk4aSKgoMzdVKRYA)

#### Explanation

Remember that a string is an array of characters, so operations like `O` will apply to each individual character.

```
OÆPẠ
O        Ord; cast each character to a number
 ÆP      Is it ÆPrime? gives 1 for truthy and 0 for falsey
   Ạ     Ạll; returns 1 if the array contains no falsey values
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÇpW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cHtB@P//AUX56UWJubmZeekKAaVVVTmpxQpqCs75KakK7vk5aQA)

---

```
Ç   # To ASCII array.
 p  # Is prime?
  W # Min value from.
```

---

`ÇpP` also works.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. I had `ÇpP`.

Comment: @Riley I'm surprised I was beaten by a Jelly answer, I answered hella quick, all I had to do was grab the ASCII command heh.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda s:all(x%i for x in map(ord,s)for i in range(2,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc6xDoIwEAbg3ae4NDGU2EjU6IBhYkA3EtzU4ZQWmrSUlA4QwrNjO3rD/@e@5a6fXGu60yqy16pQf2qEIUWl6LiVIIyFEWQHGntqbM2GOJAMZLFrOD2yMY7XgC7gkyBvCCN4r86h/sZDUiWVr@y686nxcQtb2U6D/A6EWfLyE6TMC1@5qTkURolAVmpO3ukGoLeyczSa08NlgXmJ9v68Rkct7y11MQPh03/1Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
ZpA
```

Outputs `1` for prime string, `0` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6rA8f9/dVtrbXUA)

#### Explanation

```
     % Implicit input
Zp   % Isprime. Applies element-wise to the code point of each entry
A    % All. Gives 1 iff all results are non-zero.
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
ạṗᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhQ93Tn@4dcL//0qJKEAJAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
all(`elem`"%)+/5;=CGIOSYaegkmq")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802MSdHIyE1JzU3QUlVU1vf1NrW2d3TPzgyMTU9O7dQSfN/bmJmnoKtQko@l4KCQkFRZl6JgopCmoKSfrB@sNJ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
q:i:mp:&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9Aq0yq3wErt//9Ez2BTAA)

#### Explanation

```
q         e# Read input
 :i       e# Convert to code points
   :mp    e# Check if each is prime
      :&  e# Reduce by AND
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 113 bytes

```
p(int c){for(int i=1;++i<c;)if(!(c%i))return 1;return 0;}c(char*s){char*a="p";while(*s++)if(p(*s))++a;printf(a);}
```

Comment: You can do `for(int i=1;++i<c;)` for your first for-loop to save 1 byte.

Comment: You can always omit `int` return type and argument type (if there's no other types) in C

Comment: I reduced the size from 137 to 113 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
∧/1pco⎕UCS⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdOSM1Ofv/o76pzpHqKWl5xepcjzqW6xsWJOcDxUKdg4EkSNl/BTAAq@ZST0xNV@dCFfEMNkUXQgFokvrB@sFoQrbW2mgiuYkhHuiqAjIqizOTi9FEY4AAXWGAszuakHN@SqqCe35OGrrSoszcVHUA)

#### Explanation

```apl
⎕CY'dfns' This allows us to use pco
⎕UCS⎕     Convert the characters in the input to its respective code points
1pco      pco with 1 as the left argument gives 1 iff the right argument is prime
          This is applied across the array of code points
∧/        Reduce by AND; return 1 if all elements are truthy, otherwise give false
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 46 bytes

**45 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```pl
$_=y///c==grep!/^(11+?)\1+$/,map"1"x ord,/./g
```

[Try it online! (`-l` added to run all tests at once)](https://tio.run/##VcGxDsIgEADQ/b6iNh00VC8MnQxx6FDdSHBsNJeWIgkIAQf786Kr70WdXFdKcxcrIk5CmKTjBm9bztlpN3LWYOsp1rx@VyHNLR7QlELaAF1UB/QHUKECcWTg6XpWIB9rtlOG8Qek7Afow6yrIbgFZLJef0J82fDMZR/dFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
all(pracma::isprime(utf8ToInt(scan(,''))))
```

Reads from `stdin`, requires the `pracma` (practical math) package to be installed. Checks if all the UTF-8 encoding of the characters are prime. Unfortunately, this won't work on TIO...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzEnR6OgKDE5N9HKKrO4oCgzN1WjtCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR11dEwj@Gxv8BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
And@@PrimeQ@ToCharacterCode@#&
```

Quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 28 bytes

```
[_l;||q=q*µasc(_sA,a,1)]?q=0
```

This prints -1 for non-prime strings, and 0 for prime ones. That is opposite to QBasic's usual approach to true/false, but this is the shortest way t comply with the 'consistent values' criterium. Output would otherwise be 0 or 1/-1.

### Explanation

```
[    |          FOR a = 1 to
 _l |             the length of
   ;              A$ (read from the cmd line)
q=q*            Multiply q (which starts as 1) by
µ                -1 if the following is prime, 0 otherwise:
 asc(       )   take the ASCII value of
     _sA,a,1      a substring of A$, starting at pos a, for 1 char
]               NEXT
?q=0            If we've tested all chas in the string, print -1 if q=0 
                and we've found a non-prime, or a 0 for prime strings
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
FreeQ[PrimeQ@ToCharacterCode@#,1<0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfrSg1NTA6oCgzNzXQISTfOSOxKDG5JLXIOT8l1UFZx9DGIFbtP1A6r0TBIU3BQSkxNV2JC5nvGWyKKoACUKT0g/WDUQRsrbVR@LmJIR6oKgIyKouBLkURiwECVEUBzu4oAiDHK7jn56ShKgN5Uuk/AA)

*-2 bytes from @JungHwanMin*

Comment: -2 bytes: `FreeQ[PrimeQ@ToCharacterCode@#,1<0]&`

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 60 bytes

```cs
s=>s.All(i=>Enumerable.Range(2,(int)i-2).All(j=>((int)i)%j))
```

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` into your byte count here.